# XPath for sibling text?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, scrapy

HTML content:

```
<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Release Date:</h4> 26 April 2019 (USA)
    <span class="see-more inline"></span>
</div>
```

My XPath:

```
>>> response.xpath("//div[@class='txt-block']/h4[contains(text(), 'Release Date')]/parent::div/text()")
[<Selector xpath="//div[@class='txt-block']/h4[contains(text(), 'Release Date')]/parent::div/text()" data='\n    '>,
 <Selector xpath="//div[@class='txt-block']/h4[contains(text(), 'Release Date')]/parent::div/text()" data=' 26 April 2019 (USA)\n    '>,
 <Selector xpath="//div[@class='txt-block']/h4[contains(text(), 'Release Date')]/parent::div/text()" data='\n    '>]
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting a list with three results?  It should return only one. With actual Release Date: `26 April 2019 (USA)`.

Comment: Was your question answered?  If not, follow-up with why not; if so, please accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This part of your XPath,

```
//div[@class='txt-block']/h4[contains(text(), 'Release Date')]
```

selects the `h4`.  Then `/parent::div` selects the parent `div`.  From there, the final step, `text()`, selects all text node children of that div, of which there are three:  two with whitespace only, and one with `" 26 April 2019 (USA)\n    "`.

If you only want `26 April 2019 (USA)`, use this XPath instead:

```
//div[@class='txt-block']/h4[.='Release Date:']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

**Notes:**

- You can wrap that in `normalize-space()` to consolidate whitespace.
- I've shown you how to test the string value of `h4` instead of using `contains()`, but your original condition would work as well.